# Quasar - Support multiple environments

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, quasar-framework, quasar

I’m trying to create project with multiple environments: staging, prod, test + development obviously.
With Vuejs that’s pretty straightforward

```
vue-cli-service build --mode staging
```

And create `.env.staging` file.

Important note that process.env should be accessed from quasar.conf file in order to set different publicPath for each env.

How can I achieve this behavior at Quasar?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check out the `@quasar/qenv` extension it seems to support multiple environments. https://github.com/quasarframework/app-extension-qenv

Another approach, as I am using Firebase Hosting and both staging and production hosting is in the same project ... I had the idea of using `quasar build -d` (debug mode) as staging and `quasar build` as production, each with its own `dist` folder, and I set a DEPLOY_MODE env variable in `quasar.conf.js` accordingly:

```
build: {
      distDir: ctx.debug ? `dist/${ctx.modeName}-dev` : `dist/${ctx.modeName}`,
      env: {
        DEPLOY_MODE: ctx.prod && !ctx.debug ? 'PRODUCTION' : (ctx.prod && ctx.debug ? 'STAGING' : 'DEV')
      },
...
```

I used the `dotenv` extension and have an .env.prod and .env.dev file. Within .env.prod I define the production and staging specific keys, e.g. API_KEY=blah, API_STAGING_KEY=blah, then in my boot file, I use process.env.DEPLOY_MODE to determine which keys to use in my
production env file.

```
if(process.env.DEPLOY_MODE === 'staging') {
   const API_KEY = process.env.API_STAGING_KEY
} else {
   const API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY
}
```

I suspect @qenv is more elegant but this was enough for my simple project.

Comment: quasarframework/app-extension-qenv on GitHub has the following note: April 7, 2021: The NPM package for this package has been deprecated and the Github repo archived.

Answer (score 0):

With dotenv, I use this solution to manage multiple configuration files. You need to use at least one env variable (here ENV_VAR). In quasar.conf.js

```
const env = require('dotenv').config({ path: `variables.${process.env.ENV_VAR.toLowerCase()}.env` }).parsed

module.exports = function (ctx) {
  // etc.
  build: { // override quasar env
    env: {
      ...env
    },
  // etc.
```

you can have as many configuration files as you want :

in variables.dev.env :

> VARENV=dev

in variables.stg.env :

> VARENV=stg

in variables.prd.env :

> VARENV=prd

You can try this solution declaring this ENV_VAR

```
export ENV_VAR=stg
 
quasar dev
```

Note : If you use Docker, you will have to build one image by environment or you will have to build the project at run.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on same thing on my project and found this on the Quasar Framework website

For VITE
https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/handling-process-env

For Webpack
https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/handling-process-env

Comment: For Vite also should read this https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html